# How long to wait for get api key or response from developer@support from BestBuy?

Tags: best-buy-api

How long to wait for get api  key or response from developer@support from BestBuy?
I get a message with some text in https://developer.bestbuy.com/secure/dashboard:
"The admin for your company has been notified of your request and you will need to be approved."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about BestBuy internal processes, not a programming problem.

Comment: Sorry, but you are deeply mistaken - this question is directly related to the bestbuy api - getting the key, - this is the work with the api by best buy

Comment: Additionally, nowhere else can I find information about obtaining an api key, - and why is so long ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a new request with my domain email and i get a new api key. You need to specify the domain's mail and no other and you will get a key in a few minutes.

Comment: I've been trying to get an API key. I created a best buy account with my gmail, still no results. What do you mean by domain email?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a paid email with your company's name as the domain for the email... e.g "bob@mycompany.com"

Comment: @JacobBroughton you're correct but when you request an api key and it's sends notification to the "admin", who is actually notified? I thought maybe I'd see an email sent to admin@domain.com but nothing was sent there.  I contacted bestbuy support to ask for clarification and if I get it I will update here.